# keep getting this error in this system "linker command failed with exit code 1"

Tags: c, function, switch-statement

I'm making a menu system where the user inputs a certain amount of numbers and the system outputs the average, and the sum, then it displays the numbers the user inputted into the system but I haven't been able to get far since I get this error message "clang: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)".

````c
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#define LIMIT 1000
#define PAUSE system("pause")

//prototype functions

int getChoice();
int getNumbers(int numbers[], int eSize);
void displayAllNumbers(int array[], int eSize);
void displayAverage(int numbers[], int eSize);
void showSum(int numbers[], int eSize);

int main(){

int choice;
int numbers[LIMIT] = {0};
int eSize = 0;

do{
    choice = getChoice();
    switch(choice){
        case 1: //get a bunch of numbers from user
            eSize = getNumbers(numbers, eSize);
            break;
        case 2: //show the sum of the user-entered numbers
            showSum( numbers, eSize);
            break;
        case 3: //show the average of the user-entered numbers
            displayAverage(numbers, eSize);
            break;
        case 4: //show the numbers
            displayAllNumbers(numbers , eSize);
            break;
        case 5: //quit the program
            printf("thank you for using my program!\n");
            PAUSE;
            break;
        default:
            printf("invalid choice... please try again!\n");
            PAUSE;
            break;
    }//end of switch

}while(choice != 5);
//end of dowhile


}//end of main```
````

Comment: What's the complete error message?

Comment: "_displayAllNumbers", referenced from:
      _main in arrayIntroLuisDuarte-9d0673.o
  "_getChoice", referenced from:
      _main in arrayIntroLuisDuarte-9d0673.o
  "_getNumbers", referenced from:
      _main in arrayIntroLuisDuarte-9d0673.o
  "_showSum", referenced from:
      _main in arrayIntroLuisDuarte-9d0673.o
ld: symbol(s) not found for architecture x86_64
clang: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)

Answer (score 1):

Linker errors usually occur when compiler cannot find functions definitions used in program.
You may not be compiling other source files. If definition of functions:

```
int getChoice();
int getNumbers(int numbers[], int eSize);
void displayAllNumbers(int array[], int eSize);
void displayAverage(int numbers[], int eSize);
void showSum(int numbers[], int eSize);
```

are in another file say `functions.c` and `main.c` contains `main()` function then you will have to compile them as `clang main.c functions.c <other options> -o <output file>`

Answer (score 0):

The source file which you have shown contains only the definition of `main()`. Other helper functions like `getChoice()` etc are just declared, and the definition is missing in the current file. If the definitions for these helper functions are in other files, then those should also be compiled.

Assuming that `main()` is included in `main.c` and helper functions are in `helper.c`, then the command to compile them in gcc would be

```
gcc main.c helper.c -o executive_name
```

A better way to deal with this would be to put all the function prototypes(aka declarations) in a header file, say `helper.h`, and include the helper file in both `main.c` and `helper.c`